# Apache ProxyPass doesn't work for multiple levels of path and enable proxypass for subdomains

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have two problems in setting Proxypass. I have setup the Proxypass in my Apache settings.

for example:

```
ProxyPass / http://www.domainname.com:8080/ 
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.domainname.com:8080/
```

I have the ROOT webapp in my tomcat to handle all the requests.
The following links work no problem:

```
http://www.domainname.com:8080/anypath1/anypathxxx
http://www.domainname.com:8080/anypath2/anypathxxx
```

but the followings to Apache do not work:

```
http://www.domainname.com/anypath1/anypathxxx
http://www.domainname.com/anypath2/anypathxxx
```

How do I fix the setting?

Another problem: 
How do I setup wildcard proxypass for subdomains so that: 
http://zzz.domainname.com/anypath1/anypathxxx proxypass to http://zzz.domainname.com:8080/anypath1/anypathxxx?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: In which file and which section did you put the `ProxyPass` rules? When you say that the links to Apache "do not work", what do you mean exactly? Do you get a timeout? A 404? An error message?

Answer (score 0):

I'am massively using Apache to loadbalance lots of Tomcats. I would strongly recommend mod_jk Apache Tomcat Connector for this case/job -> [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/). It is really easy to setup and truly stable!

Just install it from a repository, download binary (Windows) or build it from source.

Afterwards follow the quick start tutorial -> [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/quick.html)

Also your second question (wildcards) could be solved this way.